# Javascript sum checkboxes for if/else statment

Tags: if-statement, input, sum

So I have a script that will sum the values of checkboxes on my page, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to write an if/else if statement based on the value returned. I think the script would look something like this, but the fine folks on here seem to be pretty knowledgeable so any tips would be great!

Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function updateSum() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".sum:checked").each(function(i, n) {total += parseInt($(n).val());})
  $("#total").val(total);
}

if (total == 0) {
    "<input type="text" value="Great Job">";
else if (total == 3) {
    "<input type="text" value="Good">";
else 
    "<input type="text" value="Ok">";
}

// run the update on every checkbox change and on startup
$("input.sum").change(updateSum);
updateSum();
```

})

Comment: `if (total == 0) { "<input ...` this is not how js works (invalid js - error - check F12 console) - what do you want to do within the if's body ? also - read up some js primer

Comment: well, spoke too soon, technicly this is not an error, but `if(true){ "string" }` does not do anything by itself

Comment: I'm more familiar with how to write an if statement in php. I'm trying to put the text, "great job" etc in an input field so I can echo it on a redirect

Comment: well js works only on an already avaliable HTML page - there is no redirect (so you can add,remove,change what already is there) - the closest approach (but a bad one) would be `document.write('<input type="text" value="Ok"/>')` or such

Comment: Is     document.getElementById("").innerHTML = "; the best way to write it?

Comment: no the best way since you are already using jquery would be `.append` or such. see this fiddle for a [starting point/example](https://jsfiddle.net/rkmdc58e/6/)